# How to show data in a textview with room persistence in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

Hi I'm doing a project for university and I'm using room persistence to manage my sqlite database but It's kind of confused to full understand room persistence and now I want to show some data that is in my tables in textviews or spinners but I don't know how.

I already show data in a RecyclerView like a list, I know that I have to create an Adapter etc. But in other controls like textviews or spinners or another thing I don't have idea!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example which I show all user first name from database line by line to a `TextView`

```
val resultBuilder = StringBuilder()
for (user in users) {
    resultBuilder.append(user.firstName).append("\n")
}
text_view_result.text = resultBuilder
```

**Note**

`users` is the list that I received from database

Hope it help